# Convert a string to decimal with specific format

Tags: c#

I need to convert a string to decimal with specific format in C#. This string can be in different formats. For example it can be: `20` or `20.5`.

I need it to convert to `xx.xxx`. Is there is a method to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. This will also provide more context as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Typically it's the other way around: you have a decimal and you format it as a string. A decimal is just a value, it doesn't have any formats.

Answer (score 5):

C# `decimal` values are **binary**. They do not have a human-readable format and  can **NEVER** have a human-readable format. Anything you see otherwise is a convenience provided by the debugger or other tooling. If you need a decimal formatted in a certain way, what you really need is a **string**.

That said, the `decimal` type is a good intermediary to be sure you get the correct desired string output: first `Parse()` the original string value to a decimal, then convert from a decimal to the final formatted string result using the decimal's `ToString()` method.

Finally, it's important to understand cultural and internationalization issues mean converting between strings and true numeric values is far more error-prone and slow than we'd like to believe. It's something to avoid. Therefore the best strategy is usually parsing a value into an unformatted decimal as quickly as possible, and then keeping it there as long as possible — until the *last possible moment* before you need to format it for output.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the format like the below:

```
string t = "2020.5";

var d = decimal.Parse(t).ToString("00.000");
```

If your string contains any special character you need to sanitize it before you parse it. E.g. if the string contains space you can replace it with empty char like this:

```
t = t.Replace(" ", "");
```